# Upload an RPM to Artifactory from Gradle

Tags: gradle, rpm, artifactory, yum

How can I upload an RPM file to Artifactory using Gradle? Gradle always uploads the files using a maven-style directly layout which is inappropriate for a YUM repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that Gradle insists on uploading everything in a maven-style directory format of `group-id/version/artifact`, while a yum repository needs a flat layout. There are two approaches here - using the Artifactory plugin or Gradles newer publishing mechanism. I could only get this to work with the latter.

I assume here that you're using the [Gradle ospackage plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin) and already have an RPM build created. In my case the name of the RPM task is `distRpm`. For example:

```java
task distRpm(type: Rpm) {
    packageName = 'my_package'
    version = version
    release = gitHash
    arch = 'X86_64'
    os = 'LINUX'
    // Etc
}
```

Add the ivy publish plugin to your project:

```java
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'
```

And then add a publishing block:

```java
publishing {
    publications {
        rpm(IvyPublication) {
            artifact distRpm.outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()
            /* Ivy plugin forces an organisation to be set. Set it to anything
               as the pattern layout later supresses it from appearing in the filename */
            organisation 'dummy'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        ivy {
            credentials {
                username 'yourArtifactoryUsername'
                password 'yourArtifactoryPassword'
            }
            url 'https://your-artifactory-server/artifactory/default.yum.local/'
            layout "pattern", {
                artifact "${distRpm.outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile().getName()}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Ivy Publication allows you to specify the directory and filename pattern for upload. This is overwritten to be simply the exact filename of the RPM.

Comment: I got "Gradle publish attemps to upload RPM to Artifactory YUM repo twice" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001668/gradle-publish-attemps-to-upload-rpm-to-artifactory-yum-repo-twice-second-time#comment69674847_40001668 with this approach

Comment: This is a **bad solution**, simple because it will break when using more than one publication, or, like for @popalka, when uploading multiple artifacts. You should use a real pattern instead of hardcoding the name of the single file you expect.

Comment: Since the Ivy placeholder `[originalname]` is not implemented yet in Gradle, you should use another placeholder (e.g. `[module]`) and put the file name into that property. Check out [this minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48829037/3950370).

Answer (score 1):

This is my code snippets with Gradle Artifactory Plugin

Apply plugins:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
```

Configure artifactory

```
artifactoryPublish {}.dependsOn(buildRpm)

publishing.publications.create('yum-publication', IvyPublication) {
        artifact buildRpm.outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()
}



artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://artifactory.acme.com/artifactory'   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        //A closure defining publishing information
        repository {
            repoKey = 'demo-yum'   //The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            username ="${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            ivy {
                 artifactLayout = "${buildRpm.outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile().getName()}"
            }
        }
        defaults {
            //List of Gradle Publications (names or objects) from which to collect the list of artifacts to be deployed to Artifactory.
            publications ('yum-publication')

            publishBuildInfo = false   //Publish build-info to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishArtifacts = true   //Publish artifacts to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishPom = false   //Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default).
            publishIvy = false   //Publish generated Ivy descriptor files to Artifactory (true by default).
        }
    }
}
```