# How do I de-reference a collection of Gradle publications?

Tags: gradle, groovy, artifactory, ivy

SOLVED - see the end of this post.

When publishing Ivy publications individually, how can I then reference the collection in my subprojects section?

I'm working with tasks that build rpms inside a nested iteration - they look a bit like this:

```
def addWebServerTasks(aProject, hostId) {
    aProject.with {
        task "buildRpm_${hostId}"(type: Rpm, dependsOn: "templates_${hostId}") {
        ...
        }
        publishing.publications.create("${project.name}-${hostId}", IvyPublication) {
            artifact tasks."buildRpm_${hostId}".outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()
        }
    }
}
```

This creates 8 RPMS with filenames in the format: subproject-env-region-hostname-version_branchname.rpm.  Here's a sample:

```
web-server-config-DEV-EMEA-dev.server.com-1.1.0_feature_yum_upload_SNAPSHOT.noarch.rpm
web-server-config-UAT-EMEA-uat.server.com-1.1.0_feature_yum_upload_SNAPSHOT.noarch.rpm
web-server-config-UAT-APAC-uat.server.com-1.1.0_feature_yum_upload_SNAPSHOT.noarch.rpm
web-server-config-PROD-APAC-prod1.server.com-1.1.0_feature_yum_upload_SNAPSHOT.noarch.rpm
web-server-config-PROD-APAC-prod2.server.com-1.1.0_feature_yum_upload_SNAPSHOT.noarch.rpm
```

I have declared a repository to publish to as below, but the URL it's trying to upload to does not match the RPM name.

```
subprojects {
    publishing {
        repositories {
            ivy {
                credentials {
                    username yumDeployUser
                    password yumDeployPassword
                }
                url yumRepo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For each RPM, I can see output like the following, where the RPM file name is not the same as the one created on the filesystem - in fact, for all of the above RPMs, it tries to upload to the same path.

```
:web-server-config:generateDescriptorFileForWeb-server-config-DEV-EMEA-dev.server.comPublication
:web-server-config:publishWeb-server-config-DEV-EMEA-dev.server.comPublicationToIvyRepository
Upload https://artifactrepository/artifactory/yum/foo/myproject/web-server-config/1.1.0-feature_yum-upload-SNAPSHOT/web-server-config-1.1.0-feature_yum-upload-SNAPSHOT.rpm
```

What's missing is the "env-region-hostname" part of the filename.  Why is this being dropped?

NOTE:  I'm attempting to follow the publishing solution from (the accepted answer to) [Upload an RPM to Artifactory from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249033/upload-an-rpm-to-artifactory-from-gradle)

**SOLUTION:**
According to the Gradle documentation, there should be a [originalname] built-in pattern available, but it doesn't seem to be implemented.  As a workaround, override and then use the [module] pattern as follows:

```
def rpmFile = tasks."buildRpm_${hostId}".outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()
publishing.publications.create("${project.name}-${hostId}", IvyPublication) {
    artifact rpmFile
    module rpmFile.getName()
}
```

And then your publishing section should look like this:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            credentials {
                username "${citiEarUser}"
                password "${citiEarPassword}"
            }
            url "${yumRepo}"
            layout 'pattern', {
                artifact "[module]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll edit the post to make it a bit clearer, but the main problem is the upload URL being used does not match the RPM artifact filenames.

Comment: Could you try using `layout 'pattern', { artifact '[originalname]' }'`? It should apply a general pattern for using **only** the file name.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not quite clear on what you mean... [originalname] doesn't seem to be a valid option.

Comment: According to [this documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#patterns) on Ivy patterns, which is linked at the bottom of the Gradle documentation on [`IvyArtifactRepository`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.IvyArtifactRepository.html), it is a valid placeholder (since version 1.4). This is the reason why I wanted to give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I see that too... but unfortunately, I get output like this:  
`Upload https://artifactrepository/artifactory/yum/foo/%5Boriginalname%5D`

Comment: Ok, looks like this has been a recurring bug since 1.4... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-631  and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the `[originalname]` placeholder is not implemented yet, you could use another placeholder to provide the file name for your custom pattern:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myPub(IvyPublication) {
            artifact myFile
            module myFile.name
            organisation 'myOrg' // required for some unknown reason
        }
    }
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url myUrl
            layout 'pattern', {
                artifact '[module]'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked - thank you!  I will update my original post to show the solution as applicable to my scenario.